# svn - replicating a commit on another repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, diff, commit

I've got a couple of projects that are almost identical with a slight difference in their "view" layers. If I commit a change to one project and everything goes fine, I need to do the same for the other ones, but this takes a lot of time. So the question is, is there any way to automatically do the following (preferably in **Eclipse**):

1. Check a revision commit and see which files have been added and do
   the same to the other repos.
2. If some files have been deleted then delete them in the other repos.
3. If a file has been modified then try to merge the differences or
   show a diff between the modified file and the unmodified version of
   the other repositories.

I would appreciate it if someone could suggest a tool for this issue or some information on how I could write one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well it will work for the added/removed files, but you can export a patch (either using `svn diff` or the "create patch" menu item from TortoiseSVN or similar) containing your change, then you can import that patch (using `svn patch` or the "apply patch" menu item or similar in a GUI client). This will apply the changes to your working copy. You can then review those changes and commit them if they worked out.